# Question about the difference between 2 dates, which is the right approach?

Tags: algorithm, date, datetime, difference

I've been recently asked to do a simple exercice to calculate the difference between 2 dates.

**first date** is **the birth date**, **second date** is the **actual date** (or any date entered as the end date) let's call it **"end date"**.

Format: **Year**, **Month**, **Day** (we don't care about hours for now)

Here is the deal :

The birth date : **2021, 02, 11** 
The end date   : **2022, 02, 10**

The difference between these 2 dates is : **11 months and 30 days**. That's seems the logic answer but let's try to get a little bit deeper :

11/02 -> 11/03 = 1 month :                17 + 11 = 28   **}** 
11/03 -> 11/04 = 1 month :                20 + 11 = 31   **|** 
11/04 -> 11/05 = 1 month :                19 + 11 = 30   **|** 
11/05 -> 11/06 = 1 month :                20 + 11 = 31   **|** **From February** 
11/06 -> 11/07 = 1 month :                19 + 11 = 30   **|** **To January** 
11/07 -> 11/08 = 1 month :                20 + 11 = 31   **|** **11 months** 
11/08 -> 11/09 = 1 month :                20 + 11 = 31   **|**  **=>** **334 days** 
11/09 -> 11/10 = 1 month :                19 + 11 = 30   **|** 
11/10 -> 11/11 = 1 month :                20 + 11 = 31   **|** 
11/11 -> 11/12 = 1 month :                19 + 11 = 30   **|** 
11/12 -> 11/01 = 1 month :                20 + 11 = 31   **}** 
11/01 -> 10/02  ------------> 20 + 10 = 30

This is the reasoning behind the **11 months and 30 days**, but there is another approach (correct me if I'm wrong) which is :

the starting stays the same, which is 11/02 so the rest is :

02/2021:  17/28 
03/2021:  31/31      **}** 
04/2021:  30/30      **|** 
05/2021:  31/31      **|** 
06/2021:  30/30      **|** 
07/2021:  31/31      **|** 
08/2021:  31/31      **|**  **11 months**
09/2021:  30/30      **|**   => **337 days** 
10/2021:  31/31      **|** 
11/2021:  30/30      **|**
12/2021:  31/31      **|** 
01/2022:  31/31      **}** 
02/2022:  10/28

There is a difference of **3 days**  between the 2 dates when using the 2nd approach, and therefore the difference will be 
**11 month and 27 days**.

Which approach do you think is the right one ?

Comment: In one version, the 12th month is February (28 days) and in the other it is January (31 days). This explains the discrepancy. Saying 11 months is ambiguous/inaccurate.

Comment: Yes that's why I'm asking which one is more likely to represent 11 months, I might choose the second approach, but I need to know if I'm reasoning correctly or not.

Comment: There is no good way, simply.

Comment: Months are always problematic and there are even more approaches. E.g. a commercial year with 360 days and each month has 30 days (so you can easily compare them). You could also say that a month has 365.25/12 days and then just round the remaining days. Or just use days and no months, years are problematic too because of the leap years.

Comment: Thank you guys for your feedback, I think to avoid losing days when using the term "month", I might use years and days only and add one day if leap year